# Button link redirect issue

Tags: html, redirect, button

I have this button on my website which I am using to redirect to another page when clicked using the `onclick` function. The problem is, when it is clicked, it just shows the 404 page? Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-badge" type="button" onclick="location.href = 'user_page.php&show=1?badge=Available';"><i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#963"></i> Available </button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a button rather than an anchor?

Comment: My boss told me that he would prefer a button rather than an anchor but I wasn't too sure if you can style an anchor to look like a button?

Comment: Yeah I am using bootstrap, would it be more beneficial to use an anchor for this?

Comment: It makes more sense semantically. Anchors should usually be used for page redirection. You can make an anchor looks like a button if that's what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have your link incorrect - it should be `?` first and then `&`.

Like this:
`user_page.php?show=1&badge=Available`

That should then solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
onclick="javascript:location.href='user_page.php&show=1?badge=Available'"
```